# writing a map into a file in java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a arraylist of map and I need to write the keys of each map into a file seperated by pipe(|). keys of the next map in the next line and so on. I'm not familiar with file operations. Please help me

EDIT- sorry for not including what I have did, I have done the following and its not writing line by line, many blank lines are inbetween

```
if(alPrdt.size()>0)
{
    if (!file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("no file. creating new file");
        file.createNewFile();
    }
    fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile(),true);
    bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    //s.writeObject(alPrdt);
    for(int i=0;i<alPrdt.size();i++)
    {
        String temp = null;
        Map map=(Map) alPrdt.get(i);
        Iterator it=map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();
            System.out.println("pairs:"+pairs.toString());
            if(pairs.getValue()==null)
                temp = "";
            else
                temp = pairs.getValue().toString();

            bw.write(temp);
            bw.write("|");
            it.remove();// avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
       }
       bw.write("\n");

    }
    bw.close();
}
```

Comment: You've got to make a first attempt and show us where you're encountering problems. You can't just come on SO asking for code without at least trying first.

Comment: maybe this helps: http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html btw what have you tried?

Comment: Show us what level of understanding you have.

Comment: @Benjamin I don't believe you need the `it.remove()` line. I don't see you modifying the collection anywhere, so you shouldn't be seeing any `ConcurrentModificationException` issues. Is there something I've missed perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want the keys in this file then maybe:

```
    String pathToFile = "C:\\temp\\file.txt";
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(pathToFile))) {
        for (Map<String, String> map : mapList) {
            Iterator<String> it = map.keySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                bw.write(it.next());
                if (it.hasNext()) {
                    bw.write("|");
                }
                it.remove();
            }
            bw.write(System.lineSeparator());
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Java 7 has `java.nio.file.Files` to convert list to file where list item represents line:

```
Files.write(Paths.get("C:\\temp\\file.txt"), lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

where `lines` is `List<String>`

So, (i'm sure) you can convert easily `List<Map>` to `List<String>` by extracting keys.

Hope it will help you